# How to visit port 50070 of master in Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, centos7

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.2 based on CentOS7, a master with 3 slaves.

The problem is that I can only get Hadoop cluster's status by visiting `localhost:50070` in the master machine. And it does not work by visiting `master:50070` or `192.168.199.139:50070`, `192.168.199.139` is master's IP address.

At the same time, the slaves also can not visit `192.168.199.139:50070`.

Do I need more specified configs for visiting `50070`?

run `ifconfig` in master:

```
 eno16777736: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.199.139  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.199.255
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe0d:6143  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0c:29:0d:61:43  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 342080  bytes 318632744 (303.8 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 129369  bytes 16629889 (15.8 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 6650  bytes 2908305 (2.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6650  bytes 2908305 (2.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:fc:1a:4b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Please execute "ifconfig" on the master, and share the output with us.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the parameter `dfs.namenode.http-address` in the file `hdfs-site.xml`. The default value `0.0.0.0:50070` allows connection from everywhere. But if you have value `localhost:50070` then only connection from localhost is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

if you update your host name with associated IP in /etc/hosts then only you can access namenode from any machine. Add like below in hosts file

`192.168.199.139    master`

P.S: /etc/hosts should be same in the all machines